# How do I use hdfs file with Wand for Image conversion using Pyspark - Hadoop HDP 2.6.6

Tags: hadoop, pdf, image-processing, pyspark, wand

I am trying to convert pdf files to Image and then use pytesseract to ocr the files. I was able to do it successfully on the files which are present in the linux local path but not with hdfs path.

```
    from wand.image import Image as wi

       >>> wi(filename = 'hdfs://boboda02.boobo.com:8020/bda/clamsops/raw/personal_brella_test/09_29_2015_090902.pdf',resolution = 300)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/sam/my_env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Wand-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/wand/image.py", line 2534, in __init__

File "/home/sam/my_env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Wand-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/wand/image.py", line 2601, in read

File "/home/sam/my_env_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Wand-0.4.2-py2.7.egg/wand/resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception

wand.exceptions.MissingDelegateError: no decode delegate for this image format `//boboDA02.boobo.COM' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create instructions for the `hdfs` delegation.

I'm not familiar with hadoop, but the [documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/bde-1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.bigdataextensions.admin.doc%2FGUID-3F016B0F-235E-431F-BBC4-B9CD7BAE3222.html) to copy a file locally seems straightforward.

```
fs get --from <source> --to <local>
```

Create a simple XML file entitled `delegates.xml` with the following content...

```xml
<delegatemap>
  <delegate decode="hdfs" command="&quot;fs&quot; get --from &quot;hdfs:%M&quot; --to &quot;%o&quot;"/>
</delegatemap>
```

See the [Resources](https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php) documentation to learn about how ImageMagick loads delegation files, and which option works for your environment. You can also ask ImageMagick's `identify` utility where system paths are located.

```
identify -list configure | grep SHARE_PATH
```

If there's no `delegates.xml` file located at the SHARE_PATH location, then copy the newly created XML file to that location. Else, if the file exists, you should edit the file to include the `<delegate` line inside the existing `<delegatemap>`.

If you do not have admin access, or the system is managed via a package-manager, explore other options that work for your applications. Like `$HOME/.config/ImageMagick/`, or application directory. Refer to docs linked above.

You can verify that the delegation for HDFS has been mapped correctly by running the following.

```
identify -list delegate | grep hdfs
```

Then test it with the `convert` utility.

```
convert hdfs://boboda02.boobo.com:8020/bda/clamsops/raw/personal_brella_test/09_29_2015_090902.pdf output_%04d.jpg
```

Wand should now understand the hdfs protocol.